# GitHub `actions/checkout`: Fetch history up to before the push event

Tags: github, github-actions, git-checkout

In a GitHub Actions workflow triggered by a `push` event, I want to use the `actions/checkout` action to fetch the git history of all commits in the push event, plus the last commit before the push event (without having to fetch the entire history).

However, actions/checkout only provides the `fetch-depth` parameter, which inputs the number of commits to fetch, but that is not known. The push event payload contains the list of commits as an array, but there is no native function in GitHub Actions to count the length of an array. One could write an extra step before using checkout to count the number of commits in the payload, but that seems a bit too hacky.

Isn't there a straightforward way to fetch the history from right before a push event? That seems like a very common thing to do, so it's odd that I can't find an easy way to do it, something like:

```yaml
  - needs: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      - from-ref: ${{ github.event.before }}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `fetch-depth: 0` fetch the whole history?

Comment: Yes exactly! The point is that I don't want to have to fetch the whole history of all branches every time there is a push event. Usually in a push event one wants to compare the state before the push, to the state after the push, for that specific branch, so I only need the history of that branch, up to the commit before the push event.

Comment: @matt So what happens when for example you set `fetch-depth=10`? Doesn't it only fetch the history for the 10 latest commit in that branch?

Comment: @matt So you're saying no matter what input is provided to the `fetch-depth` parameter of `actions/checkout`, it always downloads the entire git history, but then only makes a specific number of commit histories available to the user!?

Comment: @matt I don't understand your point. When I set `fetch-depth=0`, it downloads the entire git history. When I set `fetch-depth=10`, it only downloads the latest 10 commit histories, right? So, it makes a difference in terms of bandwidth usage, time etc. Therefore, I want to only fetch a specific variable number of commits, and not the entire history every time.

Comment: Not tried this just yet, on my phone at the moment, but you could try to set the checkout actions ref to before and then add a git fetch origin aftersha followed by git reset --hard aftersha. You'd have to put those 2 git commands in a script task following the checkout action.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is my workaround:

```yaml
jobs:

  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Calculate fetch-depth
        id: pre-checkout
        env:
          COMMITS: ${{ toJson(github.event.commits) }}
        run: |
          if [[ "${{ github.event_name }}" == "push" ]]; then
            COUNT=$(( $(echo "$COMMITS" | jq length) + 1 ))
          else
            COUNT=1
          fi
          echo "fetch-depth=$COUNT" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: ${{ steps.pre-checkout.outputs.fetch-depth }}
```

As mentioned in the question, an additional step is needed before using `actions/checkout` to calculate the `fetch-depth`. Here, we first check the `github.event_name` context; if it's `push`, we then output the length of the `github.event.commits` array plus 1, otherwise we output 1, and then use this output in the `checkout` step as the `fetch-depth` argument.

It's not pretty, but currently it's the most straightforward approach I could find. I have opened an issue in `actions/checkout` to add native support: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/1444

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way that I could find for `pull_requests` was:

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
       - name: Checkout
         uses: actions/checkout@v3
         with:
             fetch-depth: $(( ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.pull_request.commits || 0 }} + 1 ))
```

Using the ternary operation mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example). So we don't need an additional step.
You could use the same format for `push` too, though the event name and commit count would need to be changed.